# Why no bounty for a +2 accepted answer?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

I'm just curious as to why no bounty was awarded for an answer with two upvotes and that was accepted by the author? [How to get weekly data from Foursquare](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/how-to-get-weekly-data-from-foursquare/44104#44104)

It's my answer (sorry I'm super lame) and am just curious as to why it wouldn't qualify so that I can try to write better answers in the future.

Comment: I see a bounty applied to that answer. (Looks like it happened less than 20 minutes ago. [edit revisions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/44104/revisions))

Comment: @AlEverett you're right, I was just being impatient!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the grace time is up, the scripts which allocate the bounty hasn't seem to have run yet.. give it another few hours, it should allocate the bounty. Else we'll move this as a bug report.

---

It's worth pointing out that Bounty allocation and answer acceptance are two separate events and one need not necessarily cause the other to trigger.